# How do I sort a list of string and numbers in numerical order?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

How do I fix id's sorting in a non-formal way like this:

```
 1
10
11
..
2
20
21
..
```

I want to print like:

```
1
2
3
..
10
11
..
```

Also, my MainData.getName contains strings and numbers up to list of ListArrays of 1000, see my app image link:

- Here is my app image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woPm0.jpg

I tried this but it gives the same result

```
int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).toArray();
List<String> rangeList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int number : range) {
    rangeList.add(String.valueOf(number));
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
    Call<List<MainData>> call = api.getData();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MainData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse (Call<List<MainData>> call, Response<List<MainData>> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            List<MainData> postList = response.body();
            // Filter out any items where "name" is blank or null.
            List<MainData> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(MainData data :postList)
            {

                if(null!= data.getName() && !data.getName().isEmpty()) {

                     //sort by name
                    Collections.sort(tempList, (mainData, t1) -> mainData.getName().compareTo(t1.getName()));

                    int[] range = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).toArray();
                    List<String> rangeList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int number : range) {
                        rangeList.add(String.valueOf(number));
                    }

                    //sort by ListId
                    Collections.sort(tempList, (mainData, t1) -> mainData.getListId().compareTo(t1.getListId()) );

                    tempList.add(data);

                }
            }

            RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(tempList, MainActivity.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure (Call<List<MainData>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And here is my Json data

```
public class MainData {

    public String listId, name, id;

    public String getListId () {
        return listId;
    }

    public  String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public  String getId () {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your listId is String ,the list gets sorted lexographically. Instead you could first convert the String to an Integer and then sort it. Below is the illustration.

```
Collections.sort(tempList, (mainData, t1) -> Integer.parseInt(mainData.getListId())-Integer.parseInt(t1.getListId());
```

Comment: bro the name is a string but when I change the code you gave me to name the app is stopping and saying:  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Item 276"

Comment: also i sorted it by id and it worked fine but when I am sorting it by name its saying ;java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Item 276"     the requirement is to to sort by name

Comment: Of course, it will throw Number Format Exception if you try to convert "Item 276" to an integer.

Comment: the whole list contains numbers like this : item with number what should I do. if I did try and catch it will ignore whole sorting thing

Comment: thank you this answer also worked. thank you so much

Comment: how can I improve my android knowledge I always run into these kind of  problems

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.sort(tempList, (o1, o2) -> {
    // splitting name with respect to white space and setting the integer part in a local variable to compare 
    Integer n1 = Integer.parseInt(o1.getName().split(" ")[1]);
    Integer n2 = Integer.parseInt(o2.getName().split(" ")[1]);
    return n1.compareTo(n2);
});
```

This should solve your problem. However, this code expects the name field of MainData object should be always in "Item XXX" format where XXX is a number.

Comment: thank you so much it worked, thanks for your time

Comment: how I can learn all of this staff bro, when I am doing something I always get stuck